# Use of unassigned variable (string)

Tags: c#, string, unassigned-variable

I have a piece of code that iterates over XML attributes:

```
string groupName;
do
{
    switch (/* ... */)
    {
        case "NAME":
            groupName = thisNavigator.Value;
            break;
        case "HINT":
            // use groupName
```

But this way I get the error of using an unassigned variable. If I assign something to groupName then I cannot change it because that's how the strings work in C#. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right that *strings* are immutable in .NET, but your assumption that a string *variable* can't be changed is wrong.

This is valid and fine:

```
string groupName = null;
groupName = "aName";
groupName = "a different Name";
```

Your code will not have an error if you do the following:

```
string groupName = string.Empty; // or null, if empty is meaningful
do
{
    switch (/* ... */)
    {
        case "NAME":
            groupName = thisNavigator.Value;
            break;
        case "HINT":
            // use groupName
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the `default` of your `switch` assign a value to `groupName`? If not, then that will be causing the error.

```
switch
{
  case "NAME":
    groupName = thisNavigator.Value;
    break;
  //...
  default:
    groupName = "something";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string groupName = string.Empty;
```

Just assign an empty string and your should be okej.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is unaware of the context of your switch statement (e.g. there's no guarantee that the switch will always match a case).

So it's possible for `groupName` to remain unassigned even after the switch.

You can instantiate `groupName` with `String.Empty` or use `default:` in your switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Set groupName in each **case** and use **default** key in switch statement or assign groupName to null **before** switch.